# Access MS SQL server remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server, remote-access

I've been busy going through many of the question asked under the same topic but none of them had solved my problem.

I have MS SQL 2012 standard (trial) is installed on my local PC. Also I have a MS SQL std. server 2005 is installed on a web server (Windows Server 2003) in different domain. Normally I can RDP the web server using the static IP address given by the Infrastructure provider.

Now I wanted to access my MS SQL server installed on the web server using the MS SQL management studio installed on my local PC. but I'm receiving the following error when I try to connect. I tried with the same  IP which I used to log in to the server using RDP as the server name.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

I followed almost everything in [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277/) KB. But the windows firewall is disabled on the web server. while I'm waiting for Infrastructure provider to confirm there is no other network level firewall denies access for port:1433, I would like to know are there anything else that I'm missing here?

Comment: They just don't let outside access to 1433. That's about it. So you might as well expect a negative answer from them.

Comment: Could you be using a named instance?

Comment: I don't think I got it, what do you mean by named instance? it is with the default name instance called "MSSQLSERVER"

Comment: Still I'm waiting for infrastructure provider, I noticed the IP address when googled "what's my ip" is different from the IP address used to access the website. can this be possible with public IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been resolved after forwarding the port TCP: 1433 on the router firewall.